# how to select all records from one table and some from another table in cakephp 3.6

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

SELECT myTable.*, otherTable.foo, otherTable.bar...

> how can we write above query in cakephp ? I tried this but didn't work.

```
$data = $this->Articles->find()->select(['Articles.*','Categories.name'])->innerJoineWith('Categories');
```

It giving me error near `SELECT Fees.* AS`Fees__*`.`

So instead of that, I have to write all columns of the Article Table.

```
$data = $this->Articles->find()->select(['Articles.id','Articles.name','Articles.title','Articles.description','Categories.name'])->innerJoineWith('Categories');
```

is there any solution in cakephp? please tell me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = $this->Articles->find()
        ->select($this->Articles)
        ->select(['Categories.name'])
        ->innerJoineWith('Categories');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$this->Articles->find('all')->contain(['Categories' => function($q) {
                    return $q->select('Categories.name');
                }])->select($this->Articles);
```

> `$this->Articles` in select statement will fetch all the records from
>   the Articles table and `$q->select('Categories.name')` will fetch only
>   Category name from the associated Categories table.

Ref: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7913

Comment: this solution gives the value in a different object which I don't want.

Comment: @26vivek This does not give different object. If you are getting different object then you must be doing something wrong. Please share your code.

Comment: @Sehdev `innerJoinWith()` and `contain()` _do_ behave differently, depending on the association configuration they can produce different queries, and the results will be structured differently regardless.